# How to open folder explore from web browser

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I'm a user of RoR, and I'm not good at English.

In my web application, I want to open specific folder in explore(windows) or finder(mac) when just click the  link.

How to do this?

I tried these, but they don't work as expected.

I wrote in haml.

```
%a{href: "file:///c:¥SAMPLE¥Sample_bar.png", target: "_blank"} click here!
%a{href: "file://localhost/c|¥SAMPLE¥Sample_bar.png", target: "_blank"} click here!
%a{href: "file:///c|¥SAMPLE¥Sample_bar.png", target: "_blank"} click here!
%a{href: "file://localhost/c:¥SAMPLE¥Sample_bar.png", target: "_blank"} click here!

%a{href: "file:///C:¥SAMPLE¥Sample_bar.png", target: "_blank"} click here!
%a{href: "file://localhost/C|¥SAMPLE¥Sample_bar.png", target: "_blank"} click here!
%a{href: "file:///C|¥SAMPLE¥Sample_bar.png", target: "_blank"} click here!
%a{href: "file://localhost/C:¥SAMPLE¥Sample_bar.png", target: "_blank"} click here!
```

Would you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `file_field` tag, with `multipart` html option for the form